# Webbrowser control not displaying web pages correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

am trying to use webbrowser control in my windows form application to display web pages like youtube, BBC etc. Am seeing that in some of the sites the CSS is totally out of place and scripts are not being executed. Can some help me resolve this. Also is there any possible method with which i can open IE in kiosk mode inside and windows form?

Below is the code that am currently using to launch my sites.

```
private void browser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ControlBox = false;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    toolStripButton1.Text = etext;
    toolStripLabel1.Text = webnamedisplayname;
    browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

    browser.Navigate(NavUrl);
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/18/webbrowser-control-rendering-modes-in-ie8.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After years of using the WebBrowser Control I never had a problem until recently! In my case, I was being served a Mobile version of the Pages I was requesting! A real pain, all due to a little app called: "[Mobvious](https://github.com/jistr/mobvious)"

I managed to get around this issue by using the following code:

```
private void GetWebPage()
{
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.AddressTextBox.Text);

Request.Method = "GET";

HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();

string Server = Response.Server;
HttpStatusCode StatusCode = Response.StatusCode;

if (StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
Stream ResponseStream = Response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(ResponseStream);

this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = Reader.ReadToEnd();
}
else
{
this.BadURI = this.BadURI + 1;
}
}
```